# Bash script: paste and execute an external bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm not sure the title is very explicit, sorry for that, but I couldn't find a clearer way to describe my problem in so few words.

So I'll explain my problem here (and if an admin/someone finds a more suitable title, please change it/tell me so that I'll change it).

Let's say I have the following bash script, let's call it `main.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1="foo"
var2="bar"
var3="baz"
var4="qux"

# Some command here
```

and another script, `external.sh`, which simply looks like

```
echo $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4
```

Is there a way I can simply *paste* the `external.sh` under the "# Some command here" line in `main.sh`, so that when I execute `main.sh`, it echoes "foo bar baz qux" as expected?

I've already tried to add a line like `cat external.sh` but of course the output of `./main.sh` is 'echo $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4'.

I know there are some alternatives, like transforming `external.sh` into a real bash script with 4 arguments, and execute `external.sh` from `main.sh` with $var1..$var4 as arguments, but that is not really what I want here.

So any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
source external.sh
```

or, shorter

```
. external.sh
```

See http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html